# Running 'Docker build -t imagename .' returns Connection failed error on Windows for example app

Tags: python-3.x

When I build a image using docker for an existing application I got one error like connection failed and

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

The command

```
/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends          wget          python          nginx          ca-certificates     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

returned a non-zero code: 100.

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   Connection failed [IP]

I tried  the following:
1) Proxy settings of Environment variable.
2) set experimental = true in Docker settings.
3) added my username in both docker user list and Hyper - v list.

but not yet to solve the issue.
Can you please some one help me to solve this error?

Comment: Well. Thank you for your support. Can any one help me to solve the error?